# Field lines of a vector field

Tags: field-theory, vector-analysis

so I hope the wording isn't too bad since I have to translate it by myself:

Create a vector field $V: \mathbb R^3 \to \mathbb R^3$ which has

$\gamma_{r,\theta} : t\mapsto \begin{pmatrix}r\cos t\\r \sin t \\ t - \theta \end{pmatrix}, \quad r\geq 0, \ \theta \in \mathbb R$

as its field lines.

Now, apparently, we just have to solve $\gamma ' = V(\gamma)$.

I actually was very close to that but I'd like to get a better intuition for it. So what exactly are "field lines"? I was googling but I couldn't really find a proper definition. Are they basically "equipotential lines"?

I though of it as "the value doesn't change on the field lines: the derivative is zero there", but that might be wrong, because if I think of that I don't 100% get to $\gamma ' = V(\gamma)$.

So anyone has a idea what exactly is going on here and can help me getting the correct words for it (or an explanation)? :)

Answer (score 1):

Just take the derivative of $\gamma_{r,\theta}$ w.r.t. $t$:
$$
V := \gamma_{r,\theta}'(t) 
= \begin{pmatrix} 
-r \sin t \\ 
r \cos t \\ 
1 
\end{pmatrix}
= \begin{pmatrix}
-y \\
x \\
1
\end{pmatrix}
$$

Comment: I know but why? What is the definition of a "field line"?

Comment: @xotix. A *field line* is a curve that is everywhere tangent to the field: $\gamma'(t) = \lambda(t) \, V(\gamma(t)).$ But by reparameterization we can make $\lambda \equiv 1$ so $\gamma'(t) = V(\gamma(t)).$ See the definition of [flow curves](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vector_field#Flow_curves) of a vector field.